# VSTS Build error- Configuration and Platform

Tags: selenium-webdriver, continuous-integration, azure-devops, mstest, azure-pipelines

I am seeing this error when try to build a solution. I am trying to build selenium framework solution that has 5 projects.

##[error]C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(780,5): Error : The OutputPath property is not set for project 'Automation.CommonLibraries.csproj'.  Please check to make sure that you have specified a valid combination of Configuration and Platform for this project.  Configuration='dev2'  Platform='AnyCPU'.  You may be seeing this message because you are trying to build a project without a solution file, and have specified a non-default Configuration or Platform that doesn't exist for this project.

Comment: Does the project `Automation.CommonLibraries` have a configuration called `dev2`?

Comment: @DanielMann no, it doesn't

Comment: Then that's your problem. Add a matching platform/configuration.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you that the project doesn't have a platform/configuration that matches what you're telling it to build.

Two options:

1. Add a matching platform/configuration to the project.
2. Add `/p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true` to your MSBuild arguments when building the solution with the Visual Studio Build step.